# how to make my application (.jar) works on end-user's desktop

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans 8.0 and my problem is when I make (clean and build) to my java project....the jar will be build in the current path of the project and works good with no problems, But, when I make a copy of the jar to my desktop, the application jar doesn't run. why?

Comment: Try running the jar manually in a cmd window. You most likely need library classes.

Comment: Might be problem of missing dependency.

Comment: try maven shade plugin. it creates an "uber" jar that contains all dependencies

Comment: yes, I guess the problem is with library classes,, How to solve it please? @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: thanx a lot @Sanjay

Comment: many thanx @SharonBenAsher I will try it. wish me luck

Comment: of course this means you will need to build the project with maven which requires a strict tree structure. good luck indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the most trivial programs you cannot just copy a jar file containing your classes to a target machine and expect it to run, as Sun never got around to do a well-defined single-file deployment method for a desktop application (similar to what WAR files do for web applications).

You must essentially copy your code, and the library jars you depend on, and a launcher script telling the JVM which jars you have, and an icon if you want that and usually more too.   The lack of a standard method means that there are many ways to do it and you need to choose the one best suitable for you.

A solution for your problem here and now is to look at https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html which discusses how to deploy Java SE applications using netbeans by creating a runnable jar with an embedded classpath.  I am not very familiar with Netbeans but the steps look very sensible and will teach you the details on the process.

When you get more experienced you will want to be able to automate the process more.  The first step in that direction is to learn Maven - a bit tedious in the start but it pays of in the long run.